# Flutter positioning widgets in Column

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

I am trying to set an image in the center of Column, and the Text at the bottom of the image, by wrapping Image and Text in the Column widget and placing it in the Center widget.

Unfortunately, it centers the Column and makes Image to be above the center of the screen.

How can I solve it?

My current code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset(ImagePaths.newLogoLogin),
            Text(Strings.beALocal)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Add padding or margin on top as high as the text below?

Comment: Thanks, but it sounds a bit like a workaround. I am pretty sure it should be more generic way, that can support multiple screens.

Comment: In which widget your currently putting your above-mentioned code? Scaffold or SafeArea or you are passing directly to runApp() ?

Comment: @dhuma1981 I return this widget as home in MaterialApp

Answer (score 7):

This can be achieved using the `Expanded` widget:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Spacer(),
        Image.asset(ImagePaths.newLogoLogin),
        Expanded(
          Column(
             children: [ Text(Strings.beALocal) ],
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start
          )
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `Stack` with a `Positioned` `Text` widget inside it.

Full example:

```
void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Test")),
        body: Stack(children: [Placeholder(), Test()]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Stack(
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
        overflow: Overflow.visible,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 150,
            height: 150,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
          Positioned(child: Text("Some text"), bottom: -25),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, if let's say the text size will be raised we need to raise the bottom parameter as well. 
I am looking for a more adaptive and not hardcoded way. 
Similar to ConstraintLayout in Android or AutoLayout in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

you can use widget SafaArea or calc size of the appbar and the navigation bar, when you have this result use this for remove in height size of screen after this you can add column MainAxisAlignment.center, CrossAxisAlignment.center and add other widget in Column

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).